# How can i programmatically set the message on calls?

Tags: android, call

I am new to android development, can someone please tell me how to do this?

In my app:

- Someone calls my mobile number, they will hear 2 rings then it will automatically play my messages while they are on hold until i answer the phone.

Please guide me.

Thanks.....

Comment: That's not currently supported by Android. It would have to be implemented on the switch.

Comment: your que is very interesting but we cant handle this from our Android phone. you have to contact any celular company like Vodafone. they ll provide you this type of facility.

Comment: @323go thanks...but how it works? any sample code which give idea.

Comment: @dhaval thanks.. is there any other way to work it?

Comment: there is only one way to reject call programmatically but you cant put him on hold programmatically. i already told you its handled by cellular company they are provide us to hold call not ANDROID OS. so we cant handle it. so just forget about it. we cant do this.

Comment: hope this type of facility come in future mobiles.....

Comment: @NarendraPrajapati, I said it can't be done on the phone. There is no code to share.